# Why is my Eclipse CDT Preprocessor paths languages list empty?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, application-settings

I've imported a C++ project into Eclipse CDT (Mars.2 on Linux), and I want to add some include paths. Having browsed through [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2013/october/article4.php) I went to:

**[select project] > [right click] > Properties > Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. > Entries**

but to my chagrin, the list of languages is empty!

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: @HighCommander4: Sorry, no :-( And I now use nsight mostly, which is not even Mars.